# Image wont upload mysqli

Tags: php, image, mysqli, upload, insert

So i have this upload file, that upload images into a database. I haven't worked with Mysqli for that long so i dont know if i'm doing something wrong?

Database table (cover): id (int 11), username (varchar 400), image (longblob).

```
<form action="insertimg.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Picture" />
</form>
```

This is the upload file:

```
$name = $_SESSION['Band_name'];

$imageData = file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
$imageType = $_FILES["image"]["type"];
if(substr($imageType,0,5) == "image"){

$query = "INSERT INTO cover VALUES ('', '$name', '$imageData')";

$db->query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
}
```

Comment: Any errors showing?

Comment: What happens when you run the code?

Comment: You probably want to use `file()` and not `file_get_contents()`, since the latter treats the contents as a string and not binary data.

Comment: is ok to get the content as string, file() will return array, which you can't properly store in a database. Try adding '{$immageData}'.

Comment: you are using your querry wrong from what i see. where you specify the columns in which you are inserting? INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)

Comment: if i use file() i get this error message: Notice: Array to string conversion

putting {} around the variable doesn't help either :(

Comment: Adding (id, username, image) before VALUES doesn't change anything :(!

Is there some code that is not working with Mysqli? I have used this code with mysql 100 of times with no problems...

Comment: Try null - INSERT INTO cover VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$imageData');
Assuming id is the Primary key over here.

Comment: NULL doesnt change anything. id is primary key yes.

Answer (score 0):

Adding addslashes around file_get_contents() made it work.